# SequelizeDatabaseError: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with timezone: “Invalid date”, ParseISO from date-fns returns me an invalid date

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, date-fns

when i receive the `req.query` and I pass it to in my insomnia a date value  and a make a request all is going fine but when I receive the date it says that is invalid like you see in the screen from my logs I try to see value with `console.log`, and always when I received it from `req.query`, even when I use `parsedISO`, and I dont know why, can someone helps me?
I use `isValid` to verify my date and it returns `false`

Here me code and some screens:

```
const date = req.query;
console.log(date);
const parsedDate = parseISO(date);
const startDay = startOfDay(parsedDate);

const endDay = endOfDay(parsedDate);

const appointments = await Appointment.findAll({
  where: [
    {
      provider_id: req.userId,
      canceled_at: null,
      date: {
        [Op.between]: [startDay, endDay],
      },
    },
  ],
  order: ['date'],
});

return res.json(appointments);
```

}

the error returned is:

```
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "date", "canceled_at", "created_at" AS "createdAt", "updated_at" AS "updatedAt", "user_id", "provider_id" FROM "appointments" AS "Appointments" WHERE (("Appointments"."provider_id" = 2 AND "Appointments"."canceled_at" IS NULL AND "Appointments"."date" BETWEEN 'Invalid date' AND 'Invalid date')) ORDER BY "Appointments"."date";
(node:37307) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "Invalid date"
    at Query.formatError (/Users/dariocoronel/Desktop/practices/Gostack/javascript/repo/backend/api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:386:16)
    at Query.run (/Users/dariocoronel/Desktop/practices/Gostack/javascript/repo/backend/api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:87:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:37307) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:37307) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

[Screen from my logs in my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT1vg.png)

Comment: Please copy and paste information from console log into you question instead of using screenshot.

Comment: Where are `parseISO`, `startOfDay` and `isValid` coming from? Also `date` looks to be an object `{date: '2021-01-01T17:20:05.247Z'}` and seem to be parsing the entire object not just the timestamp string.